# Error in event handler for methd. $emit an event from child to other component in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, emit

I faced with the next problem: Error in event handler for "add": "TypeError: this.fetchSelectData is not a function".

There are 2 different components, not a child and a parent.

//CustomerModalComponent.vue

```
methods: {
   addCustomer() {
   ... 
   this.$root.$emit('add')
   }
 }
```

//StationModalComponent.vue

```
 methods: {
      fetchSelectData() {
        axios.get('/api/customers/companies')
                    .then(response => {
                        this.customers = response.data.companies
                    })
                    .catch(error => console.log(error))
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      ...
      this.$root.$on('add', function() {
        this.fetchSelectData()
      }
    }
```

Comment: Scope problem? `
    mounted() {
      ...
      var vm = this;
      this.$root.$on('add', function() {
        vm.fetchSelectData();
      }
    }`

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was solved my issue.